# QGIS regular points tool won't let me select layer as an area

Tags: qgis

In previous posts that I have read, QGIS regular points should be able to take a shapefile as a boundary layer to generate points within, but in 2.18 I am not seeing an 'area' section of the dialog box, and it instead wants max and min values for x and y (not useful for what I want--I want my points to be generated inside a specific polygon). Does anyone have any ideas or recommendations on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> (ellipsis) button and select `Use layer/canvas extent` option. Then you can assign your shapefile layer to define the extent.

[image]